Javascript-How can I change style of my app in a click and change again in a second click and return to my initial style in third click
I'm making a calculator with Javascript and I want to make a button that if I click on it whole style of my project changes and if I click again whole style changes again and at third click it returns to initial style
I don't have any Idea how I can change whole style for three times just with one button?

Please visit [ask] to see what and how you need to ask here. Post a [mcve]

Keep a counter variable, that you increase on every click. Based on the value, decide which style to apply. When the counter variable goes over the threshold of available styles, either reset it via an explicit check with an if condition, or apply the modulo operator, to keep it "in bounds."

You can create different css classes and put them in an array. Everytime you click on a button you can switch styles by changing index. Since you did not provide any code here is an example.


let styleIndex = 0;
const styles = ['style1', 'style2', 'style3']; // styles array

function changeStyle() {
    styleIndex = (styleIndex + 1) % styles.length;
    document.body.className = styles[styleIndex];
}
body.style1 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

body.style2 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

body.style3 {
    background-color: blue;
    color: yellow;
}

/* You can change the css classes depends on your choice and application */
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body class="style1">
    <button onclick="changeStyle()">Click to change background color</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




You can look into using CSS properties/variables to define the different styles for your themes (this way you can avoid defining the styles 3 times for each theme for every class that you have), and then apply the theme with the variable definitions to a root element such as your body:


const btn = document.querySelector("#change-theme-btn");

let themeIdx = 0;
const themes = ["theme1", "theme2", "theme3"];

function setTheme() {
  document.body.classList.remove(...themes);
  const nextTheme = themes[themeIdx++ % themes.length];
  document.body.classList.add(nextTheme);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", setTheme);
setTheme();
.theme1 {
  --primary-bg-color: yellow;
  --primary-text-color: red;
}

.theme2 {
  --primary-bg-color: black;
  --primary-text-color: white;
}

.theme3 {
  --primary-bg-color: cyan;
  --primary-text-color: black;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--primary-bg-color);
}

.text {
  color: var(--primary-text-color);
}
<p class="text">Text</p>
<button id="change-theme-btn">Change theme</button>



